# How to set multiple view in view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need three views in single page in viewpager and pageradapter. How can i achieve this?

what i have tried so far i have reduced the width,

```
@Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.33f;
    }
```

so that am getting three views in a page, but when using pager indicator it shows size of the list in page indicator. so i plan to do three image view in pager adapter view based on the list size. how to iterate it?

Comment: I'm not sure how this will be done, but if you're able to override the PagerIndicator's or the `ViewPager`'s size calculation to something like `int pos = currPos/3;`, that would make groups of 3. 

e.g. for current position 0,1 & 2, the pos value will be 0, for 3,4 & 5 it will be 1, and so on. Also, the total number of items will become `items.size()/3;`

Comment: am using library for indicator ,

Comment: The library will fetch the size and position from your `ViewPager`'s adapter. Change the methods to make them behave like I posted in the previous comment. I'm not sure if it will work, but it would be worth a try.

Comment: and also while pagescroll not all three view get scrolled only first item get scrolled

Comment: Mind sharing the project so that I can have a look?